# Is there a paper accomplishing finding physical law from observation without premade perception, using machine learning?

Tags: machine-learning, neural-network, unsupervised-learning

For example:
Isaac Newton finds law of universal gravitation just by looking a falling apple, without any premade perception of that phenomenon. Is it possible to accomplish that kind of discovery using machine learning?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can check this paper

[Discovering physical concepts
with neural networks](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1807.10300.pdf) - https://arxiv.org/pdf/1807.10300.pdf

I quote one of the first sentences

> Here, we present a neural network architecture that can be used to discover physical concepts from experimental data without being provided with additional prior knowledge